# Can't auto-convert xlsx to Google Spreadsheet during API upload

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm trying to get a Google Spreadsheet online generated by a PHP script. Since it seems there is no native PHP API for creating spreadsheets (could only find Java and .NET), I figured the easiest way would be to generate an XLSX and have it converted to a Google Spreadsheet.

Uploading the file works fine:

```
$mime = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
$file = new Google_DriveFile();
$file->setTitle('My Spreadsheet');
$file->setMimeType($mime);

$data = file_get_contents('my_spreadsheet.xlsx');
$createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
    'data' => $data,
    'mimeType' => $mime,
    'convert' => true,
));
```

When it shows up in Google Drive, though, it's just a regular Excel file. I have to right-click it in the Google Drive web interface and select "Open in Google Sheets" before it's converted (but the conversion doesn't have errors).

How can I force the file to be converted immediately?

Comment: Can you paste the http request into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is an api called google spreadsheets api, just use it in raw https calls. You dont need a special php wrapper though you can with zend if you must: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.gdata.spreadsheets.html

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive now allows you to upload a file and convert it when you do. You will need the Google PHP SDK but its fairly straightforward to use.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#importing_to_google_docs_types_wzxhzdk18wzxhzdk19

I think the reason for the error in your code is that $mime is the source file not `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet` which Google requires.